# Solving for complex power

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am asked to find $(1+i)^{3+4i}$

This is what I have and I wanted to know if it is correct:

$e^{3+4i [ln\sqrt{2} + i (\pi/ 4 +2\pi k]}$

$e^{3+4i ln\sqrt{2} +  3-4 (\pi/ 4 +2\pi k)}$ by distributing

$e^{3+4i ln\sqrt{2} - (\pi/ 4 +2\pi k)}$  by Algebra

$e^{-\pi /4 +2\pi k}$ $e^{3 + 4i (ln \sqrt{2})}$

Is this correct or did I make a mistake or miss a step? 
Your help and feedback would be appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

See we can also express it In other way the argument of $1+i$ is $\pi/4$ while the circle on which it lies has radius=$\sqrt{2}$ also $3+4i$ has argument $53$ degrees which I hope you can convert to radians . Note that $tan(53)\approx 4/3$ and the radius of circle on which it lies is $5$ so effectively The number can be written as $(\sqrt{2}e^{i(45)})^{5e^{i(53)}}$ .